# Specializations of std::common_type - misunderstanding, bug, both, or neither?

Tags: c++, c++17

Tagged with C++17 because that is the specification version that I am quoting from.

Here are, IMO, the relevant parts of the standard, section 23.15.7.6 [meta.trans.other].

> `template <class...  T> struct common_type;`
>
> Unless this trait is specialized (as specified in Note B, below), the
>   member type shall be defined or omitted as specified in Note A, below.
>   If it is omitted, there shall be no member type. Each type in the
>   parameter pack T shall be complete, cv void, or an array of unknown
>   bound.

With Note A...

> **3. Note A**: For the common_type trait applied to a parameter pack T of types, the member type shall be either defined or not present as follows:
>
> (3.1) — If `sizeof...(T)` is zero, there shall be no member type.
>
> (3.2) — If `sizeof...(T)` is one, let T0 denote the sole type constituting the pack T. The member typedef-name type shall denote the same type, if any, as `common_type_t<T0, T0>;` otherwise there shall be no member type.
>
> (3.3) — If `sizeof...(T)` is two, let the first and second types constituting T be denoted by T1 and T2, respectively, and let D1 and D2 denote the same types as `decay_t<T1>` and `decay_t<T2>`, respectively.
>
> (3.3.1) — If `is_same_v<T1, D1>` is `false` or `is_same_v<T2, D2>` is `false`, let C denote the same type, if any, as `common_type_t<D1, D2>`.
>
> (3.3.2) — Otherwise, let C denote the same type, if any, as
>    `decay_t<decltype(false ? declval<D1>() : declval<D2>())>`
>   [ Note: This will not apply if there is a specialization `common_type<D1, D2`>. — end note ]
>
> In either case, the member typedef-name type shall denote the same type, if any, as C. Otherwise, there shall be no member type.
>
> (3.4) — If `sizeof...(T)` is greater than two, let T1, T2, and R, respectively, denote the first, second, and (pack of) remaining types constituting T. Let C denote the same type, if any, as `common_type_t<T1, T2>`. If there is such a type C, the member typedef-name type shall denote the same type, if any, as `common_type_t<C, R...>`. Otherwise, there shall be no member type.

and Note B...

> **4. Note B**: Notwithstanding the provisions of 23.15.2, and pursuant to 20.5.4.2.1, a program may specialize `common_type<T1, T2>` for types T1 and T2 such that `is_same_v<T1, decay_t<T1>>` and `is_same_v<T2, decay_t<T2>>` are each true. [Note: Such specializations are needed when only explicit conversions are desired between the template arguments. — end note ]
>
> Such a specialization need not have a member named type, but if it does, that member shall be a typedef-name for an accessible and unambiguous cv-unqualified non-reference type C to which each of the types T1 and T2 is explicitly convertible. Moreover, `common_type_t<T1, T2>` shall denote the same type, if any, as does `common_type_t<T2, T1>`. No diagnostic is required for a violation of this Note’s rules.

Based on this, I expect the following asserts to pass (which they do)...

```cpp
static_assert(not std::is_const_v<std::common_type_t<const volatile int, short>>);
static_assert(not std::is_volatile_v<std::common_type_t<const volatile int, short>>);
static_assert(std::is_same_v<std::common_type_t<int, short>, std::common_type_t<short, const volatile int>>);
static_assert(std::is_same_v<std::common_type_t<int &, short>, std::common_type_t<int, short>>);
```

Similarly, I expect these to pass as well...

```cpp
using D1 = std::chrono::duration<int, std::ratio<2, 20>>;
using D2 = std::chrono::duration<short, std::ratio<7, 100>>;
static_assert(not std::is_const_v<std::common_type_t<const D1, D2>>);
static_assert(not std::is_volatile_v<std::common_type_t<volatile D1, D2>>);
static_assert(std::is_same_v<std::common_type_t<D1, D2>, std::common_type_t<const D1, D2>>);
static_assert(std::is_same_v<std::common_type_t<D1 &, D2>, std::common_type_t<D1, D2>>);
```

However, I get compiler errors for calling `std::common_type` with any cv-qualifier or reference added to a `std::chrono::duration`.

To me, the standard seems to indicate that the second set of assertions should succeed, yet they fail with both clang and gcc.  Thus, I assume I am misreading the standard - or both vendors have the same bug, which is somewhat unlikely (plus I always go with ME when betting on who is wrong).

Maybe the language "Unless this trait is specialized (as specified in Note B, below)" means that none of the tenants of Note A section 3.3 apply for a specialization, but that means we can legally end up with quite strange results... like a compile error when asking for this...

```cpp
using D1 = std::chrono::duration<int, std::ratio<2, 20>>;
using D2 = std::chrono::duration<short, std::ratio<7, 100>>;
static_assert(not std::is_const_v<std::common_type_t<const D1, D2>>);
```

Normal use of `std::common_type` does not require removing cv-qualifiers and references before calling it - but it seems that specializations can require that the caller must remove cv-qualifiers and references.

This just seems wrong... somewhere.  So, I'm trying to figure out... is it wrong in the specification, the vendor implementations, or my head?

---

**Update**

It appears that gcc/trunk from compiler explorer successfully compiles all the things I think it should compile, though gcc 9.2 fails, as well as all the clang versions.

Comment: @NathanOliver Yes, but 3.3.1 states that if you pass in a `const` version, it should decay it (removing const) and the `type` field is the `common_type<D1,D2>`, which is specialized.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont Yep.  Just went back through it.  Looks like a bug to me.

Comment: It's not a compiler question, it's a standard library implementation question. libstdc++ used to have a bug which was apparently already fixed. libc++ has had this right for a while. (tl;dr you're correct). Also, you don't have to go all out with chrono, can do something [much simpler](https://godbolt.org/z/9C5lwa)

Comment: Your final example compiles for me using clang/libc++ on macOS and `-std=c++17` or higher.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/z8HWlr -- building example on godbolt with clang.  Just changed it to libc++

Comment: @HowardHinnant https://godbolt.org/z/U8-08F - maybe compiler explorer is not using libc++ for clang builds??? - smack self in head - used it a long time but didn't know I had to specify libc++ there :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in your [libstdc++](/questions/tagged/libstdc%2b%2b).  Current versions of [libc++](/questions/tagged/libc%2b%2b) doesn't have the bug, as evidenced by [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/z8HWlr).

3.3.1 does mandate that it decay the arguments and recurse; [libc++](/questions/tagged/libc%2b%2b) doesn't do this.

Comment: Is the library supposed to implement the first part of rule 3, so that a user-supplied specialization just has to specialize for the decayed type - or does a specialization have to do the decay stuff as well?  I read it as my specialization only has to do it for the decayed type - and the library will handle the others and calling the specialization.

Comment: I think it should be the job of the library - with the user just implementing the single specialization.  clang/libc++ does what I expect in that regard, so I'll assume that's the answer there.

Comment: @JodyHagins If the trait is not specialized for the const types, the rules under Note A must be followed.  They involve decaying and recusrively "calling" common_type.  That recursive call could be specialized, and if so, must be respected.

Comment: A specialization of std::common_type<T1, T2> must adhere to the rule that std::decay must be an identity transform.  I read this to mean that a specialization of the form template <typename U, typename V> struct common_type<const Foo<U>, Foo<V>> is not allowed since std::decay_t<T1> != T1 for the first parameter, namely const Foo<U>.  Thus, I am not sure how a specialization is supposed to account for the recursive decay machinery.  Maybe there is some cool trick I'm missing though.

Comment: @jody Note B defines when you can specialize it; your specicialization violates Note B.  So don't do it.  Then Note A holds.  If you specialize the decayed case under Note B, 3.3.1 states the unspecialized non-decayed case has to use your specialization.